# Keras model.load_weights(WEIGHTS) provide inaccurate results

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm training a LSTM RNN for description generation using Keras (Tensorflow Backend) with MSCOCO dataset. When training the model it had 92% accuracy with 0.79 loss. Further when the model was training I tested the description generation at each epoch and the model provided very good predictions with a meaningful description when it gives a random word.

However after training I loaded the model using model.load_weights(WEIGHTS) method in Keras and tried to create a description by giving a random word as I've done before. But now model is not providing a meaningful description and it just outputs random words which has no meaning at all.

Can anyone tell me what could be the issue for this ?

My model parameters are:

10 LSTM layers, Learning rate: 0.04, Activation: Softmax, Loss Function: Categorical Cross entropy, Optimizer: rmsprop

**UPDATE:**

This is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(HIDDEN_DIM, input_shape=(None, VOCAB_SIZE), return_sequences=True))
for i in range(LAYER_NUM - 1):
    model.add(LSTM(HIDDEN_DIM, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(VOCAB_SIZE)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.add(Dropout(0.04))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is how I train & save my model weights (I generate a description at each epoch to test the accuracy):

```
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=1, epochs=EPOCHS)
EPOCHS += 1
generate_description(model, GENERATE_LENGTH, VOCAB_SIZE, index_to_word)    model.save_weights('checkpoint_layer_{}_hidden_{}_epoch_{}.hdf5'.format(LAYER_NUM, HIDDEN_DIM, EPOCHS))
```

This is how I load my model (WEIGHTS = my saved model):

```
model.load_weights(WEIGHTS)
desc = generate_description(model, GENERATE_LENGTH, VOCAB_SIZE, index_to_word)
print(desc)
```

I provide randomly generated vector to my model for testing. This is how I generate the description.

```
def generate_description(model, length, vocab_size, index_to_word):
index = [np.random.randint(vocab_size)]
Y_word = [index_to_word[index[-1]]]
X = np.zeros((1, length, vocab_size))
for i in range(length):
    # Appending the last predicted word to next timestep
    X[0, i, :][index[-1]] = 1
    print(index_to_word[index[-1]])
    index = np.argmax(model.predict(X[:, :i + 1, :])[0], 1)
    Y_word.append(index_to_word[index[-1]])
    Y_word.append(' ')
return ('').join(Y_word)
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code on how you are loading your trained data, and also how are you saving it? It is really difficult to help you without code, extract of dataset used and the random word used

Comment: I updated the question with code samples. Sorry for the mistake